# Powershell exit status

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd

what's the powershell equivalent of simply:

```
bash test.sh
```

I'd like to call a powershell script (from outside a powershell environment) and be able to get a return value of 0 if it executed successfully, and otherwise a non-zero value if either:

- the powershell executable can't be found or executed
- the script test.ps1 can't be found or executed (insufficient permissions, ...)
- the script test.ps1 can be read and executed but returns a non zero value

And then, how to access this return value, which in linux would be

```
echo $?
```

Comment: `from outside a powershell environment` - what environment? That will surely determine the syntax you need?

Comment: From a command line, for example.

Comment: Is this powershell script yours, can you edit it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply using

```
powershell -file foo.ps1
```

should work:

```
C:\>set PATH=
C:\>powershell -file Untitled1.ps1
'powershell' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
C:\>echo %errorlevel%
9009

C:\>powershell -File not-there.ps1
The argument 'not-there.ps1' to the -File parameter does not exist. Provide the path to an existing '.ps1' file as an argument to the -File parameter.
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) 2016 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
C:\>echo %errorlevel%
-196608

C:\>powershell -file exitcode.ps1
C:\>echo %errorlevel%
1337
```

Comment: So strange, I tried that and it always returned 1 in case of a non 0 exit code, which is why I dug deeper as seen in my anwser. But now it does seem to work. #puzzled

Answer (score 1):

In cmd you can use the `%ERRORLEVEL%` variable to check for any error code returned by the last command. If this was incorrect or not found this will be different from zero.
This will already take care of the first 2 cases, where powershell.exe is not found or the script can't be found.

To return an errorcode from a powershell script use the `exit <errorcode>` statement.

You can check this in PS using the `$LASTEXITCODE` variable.
To return this into your calling batch process, you can use the following structure:

```
powershell.exe -noprofile -command ". c:\t\returnCode.ps1 ; exit $LASTEXITCODE "
if %errorlevel%==0 (echo "yep") else (echo "nope")
```

Where the returncode.ps1 script is like:

```
# do stuff
exit 1234
```

Comment: If you don't need a specific error number you could also use a `throw` statement in your powershell script when something goes wrong. In that case you powershell.exe call will simply return errorcode 1, which can be enough to know something went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Provided you can modify the powershell script, you can set the exit code using:

```
[Environment]::Exit(yourexitcode)
```

Then read the last exit code with whatever app you are calling it from.